# Get value from console.log and display/print/return in a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the values printed in the console.log, and set them as values in an input field?

Here is the JSfiddle, containing all I have so far - https://jsfiddle.net/ubo1heru/

The code through which the values are put in the console.log:

```
 $("button").click(function() {
    var dishkoMap = {};
    $("select[name='diskho'] > option:selected").each(function() {
      var value = this.value;
      if (dishkoMap[value]) { // if value already exists then increase it by 1
        dishkoMap[value] += 1;
      } else {
        dishkoMap[value] = 1;
      }
    });
    // dishkoMap is a dictionary object so you won't see anything in alert.
    // open the browser console and you can see the counts corresponding
    // to each selected option
    console.log(dishkoMap);

  });
```

Comment: Why don't just create a function which besides printing in browser console, updates the value of your input field?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `function` which besides printing in browser console updates the value of your `input` field:

```
 var printToDishkoMap = function (data) {
    // Stringifying data is it is a JSON
    $('input.diskhoval').val(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
 }

 $("button").click(function() {
    var dishkoMap = {};
    $("select[name='diskho'] > option:selected").each(function() {
      var value = this.value;
      if (dishkoMap[value]) { // if value already exists then increase it by 1
        dishkoMap[value] += 1;
      } else {
        dishkoMap[value] = 1;
      }
    });
    // dishkoMap is a dictionary object so you won't see anything in alert.
    // open the browser console and you can see the counts corresponding
    // to each selected option
    printToDishkoMap(dishkoMap);
  });
```

Comment: Giving me "object Object"

Comment: @ChriChri, see my edit ... added `JSON.stringify` call